# Multiple Formula in One Cell- Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a balance on a cell after multiplying it with interest minus payment. [I need cell E3 to show E1*D3-C3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YPzH.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is a poor question, please read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question via the Edit link.

Answer (score 0):

If my assumptions are correct, you want cell E1 to not change even when copying the formula to other cells in the column.

So, in cell E3 type `=$E$1*D3-C3`.

Comment: @Laurie your question is pretty vague. If this isn't the correct answer, please update your question. Thank you